# JQuery will not display the proper time ago

Tags: jquery, ajax, momentjs, timeago, livestamp.js

I've used moment with livestamp for years now and all of a sudden it's not working correctly.  I simply want to have it say "updated XXX ago" but it somehow is taking the time offset and displaying that as "in 4 hours" instead. Please help.

```js
$.ajaxSetup({
 type: "POST",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 cache: false,
 dataType: "json",
 xhrFields: {
  withCredentials: true
 }
});

$.ajax({
 url: "https://www.mytaglist.com/ethLogShared.asmx/GetLatestTemperatureRawDataByUUID",
 data: JSON.stringify({
  uuid: "0f32cb87-eb86-4a60-9e66-e0cfd661cba1"
 }),
 success: function (retval, textStatus) {

  var bftime = retval.d.time;
  $("#displaybfdatetime").livestamp(new Date(bftime));
    $("#displaytime").text((retval.d.time));
 },
  
 error: function (xhr, textStatus, exception) {
  alert(textStatus);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/livestamp/1.1.2/livestamp.min.js"></script>

<span id="displaybf"></span>
<p>Updated <span id="displaybfdatetime"></span></p>
<span id="displaytime"></span>
```

Comment: The timestamp it's returning is indeed 4 hours in the future though. 9:00pm (GMT-4) is the returned date. It's currently about 5:00pm (GMT-4).

Comment: That's UTC time, the -04:00 should make it four hours before

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm a novice at code and was able to follow a lot of direction to get it to this point.  I've tried changing a few lines of the code to no avail.

Comment: Could the wrong time be rendering?